# How to do a PFRelation or relational database query with parse in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

How can I perform a PFRelation query so that when I select the shop it only displays the menu item associated to it.

My tables in parse looks like this

Menu Table/Class
[image]

Retailer Table/Class

[image]

In my IOS code I have two UITableViews 1) UITableView to display "shop_name" from the Retailer Table, 2) UITableVIew to display "Item_Name" from the Menu Table.

I have gone as far as displaying all the "Item_Name" irrespective of their association/relation to another table. The code looks like this.

```
- (void) retrieveFromParse{
    PFQuery *retrieveMenu = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Menu"];
    //[retrieveMenu whereKey:@"RETAILER_ID" equalTo:_shopObjectId]; //TEST
    [retrieveMenu findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *menuObjects, NSError *error) {
        if(!error){
            _menuObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:menuObjects];
            NSLog(@"%@", _menuObjects);
        }

        [_menuObjectsTableView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

I have a logic that will pass the "objectId" of the current selectedRow in UITableView1. I was hoping to use this "objectId" to perform relational queries so that only the "Item_Name" related to the shop are displayed in UITableView2, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly, each Menu object could be in more than one shop, correct? If so, this is how you want to structure your query:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Menu"];
[query whereKey:@"Retailer_ID" equalTo:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"RETAILER_LOCATION_CLASS" objectId:@"id that you passed from controller"]];
```

This will query the Menu class for all items that contain the selected retailer in the "Retailer_ID" field.